# Python regex doesn't match words

Tags: python, regex

folks!

Many thread created here about regex and unicode but unfortunately it doesnt work in my case.

I have the string:

```
 STR = "как надоела эта шляпа"
```

and

```
query = "шляпа"
```

I'm building string as:

```
compile = re.compile(u'\\b' + query + u'\\b')
```

If i try search:

```
search = compile.search(STR, re.U + re.I)
```

It returns None.
Why i got such behavior of the regex ?

Comment: compile is ("\bшляпа\b") but still returns None with re.u | re.I

Comment: Yeah, because the second argument is the *pos*ition of where to start searching for the match. Either use `re.U | re.I` when compiling or pass them as inline modifiers, `(?ui)` as part of the pattern.

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090708/3832970).

Comment: Recreated string as re.compile(u'\\b' + query + u'\\b', re.U | re.I) but still None. Maybe i need to add something else?

Comment: See my answer, and also [this Python demo online](https://ideone.com/YCv9Qb).

Comment: Please consider also upvoting the answer(s) that turned out helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search), `Pattern.search(string[, pos[, endpos]])` second argument is the *position* in the string where the search is to start.

See the values you sum:

```
>>> print(re.U)
32
>>> print(re.I)
2
>>> print(re.I + re.U)
34
```

There is no match in your string after Index 34.

So, you can either pass the `re.I` and `re.U` flags in a call to `re.compile`:

```
re.compile(ur'\b{}\b'.format(query), re.U | re.I)
```

or use them as inline modifiers inside the pattern

```
re.compile(ur'(?ui)\b{}\b'.format(query))
```

or use plain [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) where the third argument is *flags*:

```
re.search(ur'\b{}\b'.format(query), STR, re.I | re.U)
```

[Python code demo](https://ideone.com/YCv9Qb):

```
import re
STR = u"как надоела эта шляпа"
query = u"шляпа"
compile = re.compile(ur'\b{}\b'.format(query), re.U | re.I)
search = compile.search(STR)
print(search.group()) # => шляпа
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the flags to the compilation phase.

```
STR = u"как надоела эта шляпа"
query = u"шляпа"
compile = re.compile(u'\\b' + query + u'\\b', re.U | re.I)
search = compile.search(STR)
```